# Adverb for not looking at anyone completely?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Which adverb should be used when not seeing anyone completely? That adverb should not necessarily have to do with the situation when any Indian bride hides her face by a veil, so that no body can see her face completely.

In fact, I am asking an adverb when a man doesn't see anyone completely, such as when shying before a woman or when in hurry, even when that man or woman (having or without a veil) is in front of him.

The sentence:

> He _____ looked at her because of being in hurry or other reason.

I have the word "partially", about which I am not sure that this the perfect adverb, and as we always use this word for other sense, like "the door was partially closed".

> He **partially** looked at her because of being in hurry or other reason.

Comment: The manner of looking you explain can be well-described by the word `cursorily`. However, it has the connotation of carelessness or haste. It would almost never be understood to connote shyness. Please edit your post to tell us how important that connotation is to you.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking here at all. The woman in the picture is partially hidden behind some type of veil-like garment, which means that even if you look straight at her, you’ll only see part of her face. People who are shy tend to avoid looking directly into other people’s faces at all. Being in a hurry doesn’t affect whether or how much of a person you see at all. _Partially_ definitely doesn’t work, because you cannot partially look at someone – you either look or you don’t. But I don’t understand what exactly it is you’re trying to express.

Comment: I voted to keep this question but the charming image is misleading. There is a difference between someone's face being partially hidden by a veil, and just **glancing** at someone. It pains me to suggest this but the image conflicts with your request. For the sake of clarity,  you should remove it.

Answer (score 2):

When one looks at something quickly, out of lack of time or embarrassment, one often describes this as being done

> [furtively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/furtive).

For example:

> He glanced at her *furtively* so as not to draw attention to his interest in her.

Comment: Good choice - tho suggests serious intent...?